# Disable vertical Scrollbar when Dialogue is open

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When Dialogue is open, How to remove vertical scrollbar. I used modal=true. But no use.
Is there any other way to do it.

Comment: You should post your code and screenshot.

Comment: The only way is to change `body` to `overflow: hidden` with CSS or JavaScript